# Datagridview - Insert an image into a cell in a specific row

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a vb.net project where I have a DataGridView (called "dgvRevisiones") to record information about vehicle damage records.
Through an SFTP that I have previously configured, I have the photos of each damage record, my program downloads them in a temporary folder and that works perfect.
The problem is when I need to insert each image of each record in the corresponding cell.
Currently I have a code that only inserts the last image it collects and repeats it throughout the column.

[image]

Here I leave my code:

```
    Public Sub ExtraerImagenRegistrosDaño()

    Dim img As Image
    Dim imagecol As New DataGridViewImageColumn
    imagecol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
    FormPrincipal.dgvRevisiones.Columns.Insert(0, imagecol)

    Dim rutaTmp = Application.StartupPath & "/tmp"

    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(rutaTmp)) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(rutaTmp)
    End If

    For rowIndex = 0 To FormPrincipal.dgvRevisiones.RowCount - 1

        Dim idreg = FormPrincipal.dgvRevisiones.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("idreg").Value.ToString
        Dim descripcion = FormPrincipal.dgvRevisiones.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("descripcion").Value.ToString
        ConexionBD.conectar()
        Dim recoleccionidins As New DataTable
        comandoquery = "SELECT idins FROM registro_dano WHERE descripcion='" & descripcion & "' AND idreg='" & idreg & "'"
        comando.Connection = ConexionBD.conexion
        comando.CommandText = comandoquery
        recoleccionidins.Load(comando.ExecuteReader)
        Dim idinsExtraido = recoleccionidins.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString().Trim()
        ConexionBD.cerrar()

        Dim sessionOptions As New SessionOptions
        With sessionOptions
            .Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
            .HostName = "HOST"
            .UserName = "USER"
            .Password = "PASSWORD"
            .GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = True
        End With

        Using session As New Session
            session.Open(sessionOptions)
            Try
                session.GetFiles("/home/sislota/database-registros-dano/Registro-" & idinsExtraido & "-" & idreg & ".png", rutaTmp & "\Registro-" & idinsExtraido & "-" & idreg & ".png").Check()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Using
```

And here start the issue:

```
        Try
            img = Image.FromFile(rutaTmp & "\Registro-" & idinsExtraido & "-" & idreg & ".png")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        imagecol.Image = img

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: When you debugged your code - using breakpoints and stepping through it line by line - where and how EXACTLY did you identify that the code was not behaving as you intended?  If you write code then you must know what it was supposed to do at each and every line.  If you don't then you need to spend more time thinking about that before writing the code.  If you do then you can compare what it actually does to that and work out where the problem is.  Even if you can't solve the problem, at least you can give us ALL the relevant information.

Comment: You're setting a default image to the Column object (`imagecol.Image = img`). You need to set the image as a Cell value (each Cell in `imagecol` is a `DataGridViewImageCell`). But, since you're there, you could also add a Column to the DataTable and store the images there (as a Byte array, usually; see `File.ReadAllBytes`), so you can directly use the DataTable as the `DataGridView.DataSource`.